# How can I set the property value using SpEL in the XML file?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

I want to set the property named "uriVariablesExpression" as a value of Map type. It will be run as a service activator in a integration flow. And the input channel will have a message that payload has the value of Map type. How can I set the property using SpEL?

I already saw [the article](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html) about it. but it didn't help for me.

```
<bean id="gitlab-http-outbound-bean"
      class="org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler">
      <constructor-arg value="http://70.121.224.25/gitlab/api/v3{gitlab.data.type}{gitlab.private.token}" />
      <property name="uriVariablesExpression" value="payload"/>
      <property name="outputChannel" ref="redca-normalized-channel" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Why are you wiring it as a `<bean/>` ? Just use the `int-http` namespaces to define an outbound gateway; and send a message. The framework will take care of configuring the expression for you. If you must configure it as a bean, for some reason, you need to create an `Expression` object (use a `SpelExpressionParser`). However, if you use the namespace, you can get a reference to the handler using bean name `foo.handler` where `foo` is the endpoint id.

Comment: Ok, I will change. But why the manual of spring integration does introduce starting with this method when it explains http-outbound-gateway?  http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html  And which case I can use this bean?